# Set union with multiple arity

Tags: clojure

In writing a function which takes multiple sets as inputs, I would like to be able to output their set union. So far I have written down the function:

```
    (defn foo [x y]
    (clojure.set/union x y))
```

But have also tried something along the lines of

```
    (defn foo 
    ([x y]  (clojure.set/union x y))
    ([x y & args] (clojure.set/union x y args)))
```

which outputs funky results that do not match

```
   (clojure.set/union #{1 2 3} #{2 3 4} #{4 5 6})
```

Clearly I am missing some simple implementation of the set functions, while trying to build foo, a multiple arity function.

Comment: Note that the function you're asking for is exactly `clojure.set/union` already. I assume you want to do something more detailed, but if you just want multi-arity `union`, you already have it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `args` is a Seq containing all the sets you passed after the first two, but the union function expects its arguments to be sets.

What you want is to `apply` the function:

```
(defn foo 
  ([x y]  (clojure.set/union x y))
  ([x y & args] (apply clojure.set/union x y args)))
```

Comment: I had been running into this issue with functions outside of the set functions. This post certainly cleared the issues.